# Javascript Changing button inner text without chaning the icon

Tags: javascript, html

I created the following button, and want to change the inner text "test" to other word.

```
            <button type="button" id="test"><i class="fa-2x fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i>test</button>
```

I tried below method it can change the word but also deleted the icon.

```
$('button#bkmarktest').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).text("other");
});
```

Is there any way that can only change the word, but keeping the icon, thanks!

Comment: you can wrap your `text` in a `<span> </span>` tag and change accordingly without worrying for icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @Kunal Tanwar said, wrapping the text in a span solves it and using Jquery this is my approach.. assuming the button has an id of `test`

using the `.find()` method to find the `span` child

```
<button type="button" id="test">
  <i class="fa-2x fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i>
  <span>test<span>
</button>

$('#test').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $(this).find('span').text("other");
});
```

and another option would be to use the decendant selector since the span is a direct child of the button

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
  $('#test > span').text('other');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use `jQuery` since very long so here's an example in vanilla javascript.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#test');

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // selecting span tag -> you can also give it a specific id or class if you want
  btn.children[1].innerText = 'other';
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" id="test">
  <i class="fa-2x fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i>
  <span>test</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

What `.text()` method does is that it overwrites not only text but HTML as well. The easiest thing to do is move your text inside the `<i>` so it doesn't get overwitten only what's inside of it. Review the example below and notice that the icon remains -- it's because it's actually a CSS pseudo-element and is always ignored by methods and functions dealing with the DOM.

```js
$('.test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('i').text(' IT WORKS!')
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<button class='test' type='button'>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"> TEST</i> 
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution but one amendment I would make is putting the text inside of a sibling `span` element instead of directly nesting it inside of the icon `i` tag. Depending on what other styles are applied to the `i` tag for the icon this may also disfigure the text.

Comment: That would definitely be a factor if it was part of the DOM (HTML, text, etc.) but it's actually a CSS pseudo-element so they exist in two different universes. The newer versions use JS, web-fonts, and SVG and I believe they are pretty invulnerable as well -- unless the tag it resides in is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace this using Regex without adding span or any other element in that button. Here is solution:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  const regex = /([^>]+)$/;
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex,'other'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test"><i class="fa-2x fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i>test</button>
```

Another solution is to change text inside of `<i>` element:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('i').text("Other");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test"><i class="fa-2x fa-regular fa-floppy-disk">test</i></button>
```